# Jruby+swt. Can't execute the application on Amazon server

Tags: java, linux, swt, jruby

I try to launch jruby application which use swt library on Amazon EC2 server (linux 32-bit) but get this error:

```
NameError: missing class or uppercase package name (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display')
  get_proxy_or_package_under_package at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54
                      method_missing at file:/tmp/jruby222146559887633660extract/jruby-core-complete-1.7.10.jar!/jruby/java/java_package_module_template.rb:14
                             Widgets at jar:file:/home/user/test.jar!/gems/swt-0.18/lib/swt/minimal.rb:12
                                 Swt at jar:file:/home/user/test.jar!/gems/swt-0.18/lib/swt/minimal.rb:11
                              (root) at jar:file:/home/user/test.jar!/gems/swt-0.18/lib/swt/minimal.rb:6
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
                              (root) at jar:file:/tmp/jruby222146559887633660extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
                             require at jar:file:/tmp/jruby222146559887633660extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
                              (root) at jar:file:/home/user/test.jar!/gems/swt-0.18/lib/swt.rb:2
                              (root) at ./main.rb:2
                                load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099
                              (root) at jar:file:/tmp/jruby222146559887633660extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
                             require at jar:file:/tmp/jruby222146559887633660extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135
                              (root) at file:/home/user/test.jar!/META-INF/main.rb:1
error: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (NameError) missing class or uppercase package name (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display')
```

Does anyone already faced with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason: Amazon EC2 server doesn't has any possibility to render any gui. It just server with command terminal. For my case it suits any way, because the app renders only logs in gui. So I will just remove the gui part and display app logs in terminal.